# iOS app works on developer's iPad, fails immediately on in-house iPads

Tags: ios, ipad, crash, startup, launch

I have an iOS app written by someone else that I need to put on a colleague's iPad. We recently got an Apple Enterprise developer account, so in-house distribution becomes available, and is in fact the preferred distribution method in this case.

I was able to switch to the the enterprise provisioning profile in Xcode and build the app successfully. I can use Xcode to sync it to my iPad and it runs without error there. I then email the app to a colleague and he uses iTunes to sync it to his iPad. When he runs it, the screen goes black for a moment and then returns to the home page with all the installed apps on it.

Do you have any idea what is going wrong? Where can I look for more detailed error messages? I did some digging online but don't really know where to look, since the problem is so vague. Searches on "iPad app fails on startup" or "iPad app fails on launch" yield little. Some suggest simply restarting the iPad, but I'd like to know what is really going on and solve any underlying problems.

One thing that is a little weird is that Xcode generated a .xcarchive file, not a .ipa as I was expecting, when I built an archive as Apple's [documentation](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/ToolsLanguages/Conceptual/DevPortalGuide/DistributinganApp/DistributinganApp.html) suggested.

I am using Xcode 4.1 on Mac OS 10.7.2 with a 4.3.5 iPad 2. My colleague has a 4.3.5 iPad 2 as well.

Comment: Not sure what the issue is but may I recommend you take a look at testflightapp.com? It makes deployment to testing devices pretty straightforward. All you have to do is build the IPA using Xcode (Archive then Share) and upload it to Test Flight, no more dragging and dropping files to iTunes etc. Users will receive an email with a link and install it directly on their devices.

Comment: Have your colleague install [iPhone Configuration Utility](http://www.apple.com/support/iphone/enterprise/), then with his iPad connected, select his device within the config utility UI and have him send you the console output. Might give you a clue about what is happening.

Comment: @Rog - I'm not sure that TestFlight works with Enterprise distribution

Comment: @Jason it does, I use it all the time.

Comment: @Rog, Thanks for the TestFlight tip. We use TestFlight for our main app, but what I am working with now is a diagnostic tool just for me and QA. I'll investigate whether TestFlight makes sense for my needs.

Comment: 'the home page with all the installed apps on it' is called the Springboard

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My question was mostly where I could look for more information. @keno's suggestion to use the iPhone Configuration Utility was spot on. It let me view the console output of the app and debug from there. Problem solved.

Regarding the weirdness about the .xcarchive being generated and not a .ipa file, I didn't notice the Share... button in the upper right of Xcode's archive panel in its Organizer window. Sharing through that button did the trick, too.

Live and learn. Thanks everyone.

Comment: I'm curious, what did the iPhone Configuration Utility + Logs tell you?

Comment: @slf, it turns out that my app really was starting up, but then crashing shortly after. By viewing the console output, I could determine how far it got and figure out what the bug was.